# fprintf causes console application to crash

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, printf

I'm debugging a problem with fprintf. I was hoping you guys can give me some advice or even if it is a simple problem then help me identify it. My code is as follows.

```
        while(fgets(buffer, 500, filep) != NULL){
        //printf("%d\n", i);
        strcpy(result, buffer);
        result = strtok(result, " ,()[]\'");
        //printf("%s\n", buffer);
        while(result != NULL){
            //printf("%s\n", buffer);
            if(stricmp(result, strng) == 0){
                //printf("found!!\n");
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
                fprintf(Compilation, "%s", buffer);
                //printf("%s", result);
            }
            result = strtok (NULL, " ,()[]\'");
        }
        result = (char*)realloc(result, 500);
    }
```

I know this is messing and perhaps not even the best way to go at it but it is what I have. buffer and result are originially malloced with 1024 bytes. once each line is parsed, if a string is found within the line then the whole line is appended to a new file. I know the memory is messy so I'm still trying to tighten it up. My problem is that fprintf will run for many lines and once in awhile it will hit a line and crash the application. When I debug this problem in the IDE (VSexpress2012) with the printf line then I see that printf actually prints many lines after fprintf stops printing to the file. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that file output is buffered. If your program crashes, some of the stuff that you've printed with fprintf may still be waiting in a buffer, and not be visible on the file. You can use **fflush(Compilation);** to flush the buffer. Add that after the fprintf line.

Comment: an empty string `""` does not equal to NULL. For further clarifictions you should show what buffer and result are. You should show more of your code.

Comment: You need to show more code. If you can make a small, complete program that reproduces your problem it will be perfect.

Comment: fprintf() has a return value you can check to see if it failed to write.  As well, you can check the value of errno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass an arbitrary pointer into `realloc`. The problem is that `strtok` modifies the `result` pointer, then you attempt to `realloc` using this pointer. `realloc` needs the original pointer returned from `malloc`.

Comment: How do I fix this? Do I save &result into an int before I use strtok and then assign &result back to then int before I realloc?

Comment: Why are you using realloc at all? In any case, you need to just save the return value of `strtok` to a different variable. Don't EVER modify what `result` points to unless you don't plan to use it again, and with the current code, you're reusing it all over.